# Eliminar factores concretos

Tags: base-de-datos, r, datatables, dataframe, rstudio

No sé si existe una función así en RStudio, pero quería por ejemplo eliminar de una base de datos todos los factores llamados "Talleres", y que se me eliminasen todas las filas que donde en esa variable pone "Talleres". ¿Alguien sabe si existe una función así?. El programa utilizado es RStudio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No existe una función específica, tienes que eliminar las filas dónde aparezca el nivel "Talleres" y luego eliminas este del factor.  ¿Por que no armas un ejemplo de tus datos, así podemos responderte con el mismo?

Comment: Mira he añadido una imagen de los datos, es que la base de datos es de 7000 datos entonces es difícil incorporala por aquí. El caso sería que por ejemplo me gustaría eliminar "APARCAMIENTO DE VEHÍCULOS" y "TALLER MECANICO" y quedarme con las demás filas, que son los demás factores que tiene esa variable. Es que con un filter (de dplyr) puedo coger datos con un factor concreto, pero a mi me gustaría en vez de cogerla eliminarla de la base de datos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imaginando un `data.frame` como el que dices:

```
set.seed(1)
datos <- data.frame(datos.ACTIVIDAD = sample(c("APARCAMIENTO DE VEHÍCULOS", 
                                               "TALLER MECANICO", 
                                               "ALMACENAMIENTO DE MATERIALES"), 10, replace = TRUE),
                    datos.IMPORT = runif(10),
                    stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
datos

                datos.ACTIVIDAD datos.IMPORT
1     APARCAMIENTO DE VEHÍCULOS    0.1765568
2  ALMACENAMIENTO DE MATERIALES    0.6870228
3     APARCAMIENTO DE VEHÍCULOS    0.3841037
4               TALLER MECANICO    0.7698414
5     APARCAMIENTO DE VEHÍCULOS    0.4976992
6  ALMACENAMIENTO DE MATERIALES    0.7176185
7  ALMACENAMIENTO DE MATERIALES    0.9919061
8               TALLER MECANICO    0.3800352
9               TALLER MECANICO    0.7774452
10 ALMACENAMIENTO DE MATERIALES    0.9347052
```

Para eliminar ciertos factores de `datos.ACTIVIDAD`, primero eliminamos las filas que corresponden a estos:

```
a_eliminar <- datos$datos.ACTIVIDAD %in% c("APARCAMIENTO DE VEHÍCULOS", "TALLER MECANICO")
# Seleccionamos solo aquellos que no sean los que vamos a eliminar
datos <- datos[!a_eliminar,] 

datos

                datos.ACTIVIDAD datos.IMPORT
2  ALMACENAMIENTO DE MATERIALES    0.6870228
6  ALMACENAMIENTO DE MATERIALES    0.7176185
7  ALMACENAMIENTO DE MATERIALES    0.9919061
10 ALMACENAMIENTO DE MATERIALES    0.9347052
```

El tema, es que el `factor` sigue conservando los `levels` originales:

```
levels(datos$datos.ACTIVIDAD)
[1] "ALMACENAMIENTO DE MATERIALES" "APARCAMIENTO DE VEHÍCULOS"   
[3] "TALLER MECANICO"
```

no es nada malo que esto sea así, el problema puede ser a la hora de hacer alguna gráfica, ya que aún `levels` sin datos se mostrarán. Para eliminarlos, tenemos [`droplevels()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/droplevels):

```
datos$datos.ACTIVIDAD <- droplevels(datos$datos.ACTIVIDAD)
levels(datos$datos.ACTIVIDAD)
[1] "ALMACENAMIENTO DE MATERIALES"
```

Comment: Perfecto, de esta manera me va muy bien, ya que no necesito hacer gráfica. Es para extraer unas muestras y sacar unas medias y demás.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.